# jQuery move/prepend html text in a list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, each

I would like to move / prepend each list item text (Brochure A, Brochure B etc) from w`pdf_file_name` class to the `row_downloadbutton > a` then remove `row_filename`

```
<ul class="wpdf-list-style">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="row_filename">
            <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure A</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf" href="Brochure-A.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="row_filename">
            <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure B</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf" href="Brochure-B.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
    ...
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
    ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(".row_downloadbutton>a").each(function(){
   jQuery(this).prepend(jQuery('.wpdf_file_name').html());
});
jQuery(".row_filename").remove();​
```

However only Brochure A is getting repeated to the `row_downloadbutton`..not Brochure B, Brochure C etc etc

I have tried `.children()`, `.siblings()`, `.closest()` but not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each download link, get the `.closest()` common parent (could be `.clearfix` or `li` or both in your case), then `.find()` the corresponding `.wpdf_file_name` :

```js
(function($) {
  $(".row_downloadbutton > a").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend(
      $(this).closest('li.clearfix').find('.wpdf_file_name').html()
    );
  });
  $(".row_filename").remove();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wpdf-list-style">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="row_filename">
      <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row_downloadbutton">
      <a class="pdf" href="Brochure-A.pdf" target="_blank">
        Download
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="row_filename">
      <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row_downloadbutton">
      <a class="pdf" href="Brochure-B.pdf" target="_blank">
        Download
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest` and `find` like this:

```
jQuery(this).prepend(jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.wpdf_file_name').html());
```

See demo below:

```js
jQuery(".row_downloadbutton>a").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).prepend(jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.wpdf_file_name').html());
});
jQuery(".row_filename").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wpdf-list-style">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="row_filename">
      <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf" href="Brochure-A.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="row_filename">
      <p class="wpdf_file_name">Brochure B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row_downloadbutton"><a class="pdf" href="Brochure-B.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    ...
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ RRowan you are welcome @paulgv beat me to it, so it is rather you accept his answer? Would like an upvote though :)

Comment: Much obliged @kukkuz :D